# Write a SQL query in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to convert this SQL query into Laravel eloquent .

```
select users.id,count(orders_products.user_id),users.referred_by,sum(orders_products.product_price) from users inner join  orders_products  on  users.id=orders_products.user_id group by referred_by;
```

This Query get me result

```
+----+--------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------------+
| id | count(orders_products.user_id) | referred_by | sum(orders_products.product_price) |
+----+--------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------------+
| 35 |                              3 | 0           |                                900 |
| 40 |                              2 | 35          |                                600 |
| 45 |                              1 | 36          |                                300 |
| 44 |                              2 | 41          |                                600 |
+----+--------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------------+
```

please help me right this query in laravel DB Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service; you need to show your attempt first, and we'll help debug any issues you're having.

Comment: Tim Lewis @Ok Let me update my question

Answer (score 0):

If it's not compulsory you can use Laravel query builder like this implementation.

```
DB::table('Users')->select('users.id','users.referred_by',array(\DB::raw('COUNT(orders_products.user_id)')))
            ->sum('orders_products.product_price')
            ->groupBy('referred_by')
            ->join('orders_products','users.id','=','orders_products.user_id')
            ->get();
```

Visit these links to get a deeper understanding in Laravel eloquent and Laravel query builders https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries